# How to add a <span> tag to wp_nav_menu in a child theme

Tags: menus, child-theme, walker

I'm creating a website with WordPress and `Uncode` theme, and I want to add a `<span>` tag to the primary menu in the child theme (in the 'li', after the 'a') and I don't know how to do that.

I don't want to modify the parent theme, just add the 'array' 'after' in the `wp_nav_menu` who has for `theme_location`, the value 'primary'.

Do you have you any idea? Maybe with a 'walker' (or other) in the `functions.php` of my child theme? I'm not an expert with PHP/WordPress codex, so do you have a solution?

Comment: Do you like your menu item will be like <li><a href="#">Home <span></span></a></li>

?

Comment: @webHasan Yes. Or like this: <li><a href="#">Home</a><span></span></li>.
Both solutions are right for me.

Comment: If <li><a href="#">Home <span></span></a></li>  is your solution then you can use <span></span> as  Navigation Label after your menu text. See screenshot. 

http://prntscr.com/c4ssqm

Comment: @webHasan I know this tip, but it's not a good solution in my case because the Navigation Label is used in others parts of theme (like 'title' and 'data-title' of parents 'li'). Do you have an other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function has a *ton* ( or *bunch* ) of parameters which makes customization fairly easy. I believe the one you're specifically looking for is `after` which will add a passed string into the list **after** the link. An example would look like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'          => 'Main Menu',
    'container'     => 'nav',
    'theme_location'=> 'primary',
    'after'         => '<span></span>',
) );
```

And would output something like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a><span></span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`wp_nav_menu_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_args/) hook in `functions.php` to modify the arguments for the primary menu:

```
function modify_main_menu( $args ) {

    if( isset( $args['theme_location'] ) && 'primary' === $args['theme_location'] ) {
        $args['after'] = '<span></span>';
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'modify_main_menu' );
```

Comment: how to change this code that replace `a` to `span` for elements who has sub menu?